# Refreshing Grid View without opening the application again

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-access, ado.net

Is there any way through which I can refresh the Grid View without closing the application and opening it again? I am trying to refresh the Grid View this way.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Parent.Refresh();

        }
```

And I inserting into the **Access Database** this way,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting up Connection String
            string connectionString1 = GetConnectionString();
            OleDbConnection myConnection1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\\Users\\Daffodils\\Documents\\WindowsFormsApplication11\\WindowsFormsApplication11\\WindowsFormsApplication11\\PersonDatabase.mdb");
            //OleDbConnection myConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString1);
            String insertString = "Insert Into PersonTable([FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Age]) Values ('" + "John" + "','" + "Gray" + "','" + "Toronto" + "','" + "50" + "')";

            using (myConnection1)
            {
                OleDbCommand command = myConnection1.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = insertString;

                try
                {
                    // openning a connection to the database / table
                    myConnection1.Open();

                    //// SQL commnd class
                    OleDbDataReader myDataReader1 = command.ExecuteReader(); // exists as a part of SQL command class

                    //Closing Database connection
                    myDataReader1.Close();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Data was added to the table !!!");
                    MessageBox.Show("Data was added to the table !!!");
                }
                // dealing with exceptions
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // printing exception message to default output
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried using, `dataGridView1.EndEdit();` but still I have to close application and open it again.

Comment: Why won't you just redo the dgv-info-filling logic when you want it? And if you have inserted a new person yourself, you can easily just add that single row manually (same goes for delete or update).

Comment: yes. it is windows application.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are fetching the data into Grid ?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'personDatabaseDataSet.PersonTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
           this.personTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.personDatabaseDataSet.PersonTable);

        }
    }

Comment: The datagridView.Parent.Refresh just redraw the control and it's child. It does not refresh the data by any means. You need to rebind the data source to the grid in case of any insert/delete/modification etc. I guess you should shift your data bind code from Page_Load to a private void and call it from Page_Load and also call it in button2_click, after you insert/modify/delete the data.

Comment: I did that too but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the code what you did? If you paste the entire code, may be I would be able to see what is wrong and where.

Comment: See this, http://pastebin.com/KF7DE6rR

Comment: I cannot see where you have bound the datagridview to the data table? Is it at design time? If yes, you need to bind it when you refresh the data again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you databind your gridview?

```
myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

That will force the refresh of data in your grid

Comment: I am trying to use, dataGridView1.DataBind(); but it shows I am missing some directive. o.O

Comment: Can you change your datagridview to just a gridview?  Apparently dataGridView doesn't allow DataBind(); whereas Gridview Does...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: Sorry about your troubles friend.  I did notice that you never close your connection. You should have: 'myConnection1.Close();' after showing your message box.

Comment: I did that, but I still have to close the application and open it again.

Comment: @bkizer1 Doesn't the connection flush and close automatically when disposed? It is in a `using` statement.

Comment: But I am confused how to achieve this :/

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your button1 is the refresh. You can try this technique.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code for loading again the data to the grid
    }
```

then after the `MessageBox.Show("Data was added to the table !!!");`
 put this code

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

So you need to put the code on how you load your data into the datagrid in button1 event